# Redux Toolkit and TypeScript I am bloked : parameter state unknow

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i have a problem with properties of my state come from the slice (redux toolkit).
I have unknown but I created a hooks.ts with  useAppSelector , TypedUseSelectorHook, RootState.
See the screenshot.

I don't understand what I should do ?

I'm trying to convert my React Redux Toolkit app to TypeScript.
I start with Typescript but I followed the typescript courses of executeprogram

Thanks

screen1
[image]

screen2
[image]

Screen3
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to follow the official documentation for the implementation of Redux Toolkit with TypeScript : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript
and it's work, the reducers are found.